# Why doesn't my Angular component value update?

Tags: javascript, angular

component1.html :

```
<div>
    {{nums}}
</div>
```

TS:

```
nums: Array<number> = [0, 1, 2, 3]; 

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.numService.getNum().subscribe((res) => {
    this.num = res;
  });
}
```

component2.html:

```
<div (click)="addNum()">
  Add
</div>
```

TS:

```
addNum(): void {
  this.numService.addNum(6);
}
```

NumService:

```
public getNum() {
    return of(this.nums);
  }
  public addNum(num) {
    this.nums.push(num);
  }
```

Why when i click on addNum, in component1 doesn't work subscribe and value doesn't change. How to do it properly on this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are facing two problems:

1. Every time you call the service function `numService.getNum()` you are creating a new observable.
2. [The function](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) `of` creates a special observable which only emits its value once.

Instead you should have your service maintain a single observable, preferably a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) (so it retains the previous value for subscriptions)

something like this should work, in your service:

```
  nums$ = new ReplaySubject<int[]>([]);
  nums = []

  public addNum(num) {
    this.nums.push(num);
    this.nums$.next(this.nums)
  }
```

then from your component, you should not subscribe (to avoid the usual [observable memory leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject)), but expose the service's observable:

```
  numsAtComponent$ = this.numService.nums$
```

And finally from your template, you subscribe to the component variable and show its value like this:

```
<div>
 {{ numsAtComponent$ | async }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you call `this.numService.getNum()` in `ngOnInit` the subscribe method is only called once ngOnInit is executed. That happens because `NumService.getNum()` returns an observable created with the `of()` operator. Such an observable emits only once and then completes. So you get only initial value of `NumService.nums`.

Solution would be to turn `numService.nums` into a BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it.

```ts
class NumService {
  private numsSubject$: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new Subject<number[]>([]);

  nums$: Observable<number[]> = this.numsSubject$.asObservable();

  addNum(num: number): void {
    const nums = this.numsSubject$.getValue();
    this.numsSubject$.next([...nums, num]);
  }
}


class Component1 {
  nums: Array<number> = [0, 1, 2, 3]; 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.numService.nums$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.num = res;
    });
  }

  addNum(): void {
    this.numService.addNum(6);
  }
}
```